# Print 2 for loops next to each other

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, output

I was wondering how can I print 2 for loops next to each other?

These are loops:

```
for(vector<Student>::iterator it = studenti.begin(); it != studenti.end(); ++it)
        cout << "| " << it->brojIndeksa << "          " << it->ime << "  " << it->prezime;
for(map<string,string>::iterator it = ocjene.begin(); it!= ocjene.end(); ++it)
        cout << "     " << it->first << " - " << it->second << endl;
```

the output I want:

`| brojIndeksa          ime  prezime     first - second`

`| brojIndeksa          ime  prezime     first - second`

`| brojIndeksa          ime  prezime     first - second`

the output I have:

```
| brojIndeksa          ime  prezime| brojIndeksa          ime  prezime     first - second
     first - second
```

EDIT:

```
struct Predmet {
    string naziv;
    string odsjek;
    istream& dodaj_predmet(istream &);
    void sort_predmeti();
};

struct Student {
    string brojIndeksa;
    string ime;
    string prezime;
    map<std::string, string> ocjene;
    istream& dodaj_studenta(istream &);
    void sort_studenti();
};
```

`map<std::string, string> ocjene` contains 2 strings for input, 1st one needs to be `naziv` from `Predmet` structure.

NEW OUTPUT:

`| 1808          John  Doe    EJ 10`

`|       PIM 10`

`| 1809          Jessica  Doe     PIM 10`

Comment: the maps and the vector have equal number of elements?

Comment: I find using std::stringstream simplifies this effort. Consider std::stringstream leftColumn; std::stringstream rightColumn;  Then fill each column in the usual way, Next, for each line, do one std::cout << leftColumn[i] << rightColumn[i] << endl;

Comment: I don't understand it, can you please explain how it will work on my example?

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate using both iterators in the same loop:

```
auto studenti_it = studenti.begin();
auto ocjene_it = ocjene.begin();

for (; studenti_it != studenti.end() && ocjene_it != ocjene.end(); ++studenti_it, ++ocjene_it)
{
    // Print using both iterators...
}
```

---

After your edit where we see that the map is a member of the `Student` structure, I'm ***guessing*** what you want is to iterate over first the `studenti` vector, and then inside it have a loop for the `Student::ocjene` map?

Then you would have something like

```
// First iterate over the vector
for (auto const& student : studenti)
{
    std::cout << "| " << student.brojIndeksa << "          " << student.ime << "  " << student.prezime << '\n';

    
    // Then inside iterate over the map
    for (auto const& oj : student.ocjene)
    {
        std::cout << '\t' << oj.first << ' ' << oj.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that one before but everything messes up, ocjene_it->first goes to another entry of user. Example:
1 John Doe IT (random dude's entrY) 7 
2 Random Dude Programming - (someone else's entry) 9
3 Someone Else Video editing - (john doe's entry) 10

Comment: @Wolfhrat The problem is that `std::map` is ***ordered*** on the keys, so it will likely not be in the same order as the vector. Is any element of the vector structure `Student` used as the key for the map? Then only iterate over the vector, and get the data from the map using the `Student` member as key.

Comment: It is actually, `map<string,string>` (1st string input) in `Student` structure depends on `string naziv` inside `Predmet` structure, so if entered string doesn't exist inside `Predmet` structure, I'll get an error. Can I use that thing to iterate over these 2 loops?

Comment: @Wolfhrat Please edit your question to show us a proper [mcve]. Especially how the `Student` structure looks like, and how it's connected to the map.

Comment: There, if you need any other details, just tell me.

Comment: @Wolfhrat Edited my answer with another guess about what you might want.

Comment: My output is still messed up, I've already tried nested loop to get an output. I'll update my question to show you how my output now looks like.